# How to animate specific corners of the border radius when hovered in and out? (Firefox)

Tags: jquery, animation, border, css

I know how to do this for Webkit browsers but I'm kinda stuck in Firefox. The code below just animate the top-left corner while the rest just snap into places.

Here's my code:

```
$('img').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({MozBorderRadius: '50px 50px 0px 0px'}, 900);
    },function(){
        $(this).animate({MozBorderRadius: '25px 25px 0px 0px'}, 900);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that you are using the shortcut that has all four corners in one definition, when you need to define them separately

Try this out:

```
$('img').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        "MozBorderRadiusTopleft": '50px',
        "MozBorderRadiusTopright": '50px'
    }, 900);
},function(){
    $(this).animate({
        "MozBorderRadiusTopleft": '25px',
        "MozBorderRadiusTopright": '25px'
    }, 900);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Nothing happens. I added "alert()" just to make sure that the in and out functions are executed and i get the message box. Still, no change on the screen to my divs can be seen...

Answer (score 0):

`MozBorderRadius` is a property I'm not familiar with, perhaps it is deprecated? Try using `-moz-border-radius` instead.