# Animating specific corners on hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I've found a great example [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181697/how-to-animate-specific-corners-of-the-border-radius-when-hovered-in-and-out-f) discussing how to animate specific corners of a border. However, it seems i get no change what so ever. After inserting an alert into the in and out functions i confirmed that they are fired. However, any change to the cornerization are just not there.

Has it to do with how i styled the divs?

```css
div.menuItem {
    border-width: 5px 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 25px 45px 25px 45px;
    font: 30px Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    border-color: #00bb00;
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#8822cc;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000;
}
```

And here's the script.

```
$('div.menuItem').hover(function () {
            alert("in");
    $(this).animate({
        "MozBorderRadiusTopleft": '50px',
        "MozBorderRadiusTopright": '50px'
    }, 900);
}, function () {
            alert("out");
    $(this).animate({
        "MozBorderRadiusTopleft": '25px',
        "MozBorderRadiusTopright": '25px'
    }, 900);
});
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted and why now?! It's been over two years...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions/):

```css
div.menuItem {
    border-radius: 25px 45px 25px 45px;
    transition: border-radius .9s;
    /* all other properties... */
}
div.menuItem:hover {
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ucVPg/

**P.S.** Don't forget the vendor prefixes.

Comment: ?! I removed the JS-part in the fiddle and it's still working. You mean that i don't need JS at all to do that? The transition style is totally news to me, so it was pretty cool. Now, supposed i'd like to animate the div upon something else than "hover". Then i have to rely on JS, right? In such case, how can i make it work?

Comment: @KonradViltersten - Then all you have to do is set a class in your JS. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ucVPg/1/

Comment: Also, i just noticed that, although it seems to work fine in jsFiddle, on my machine it just clicks over. No gradual transition, just peep-popp. Suggestions?

Comment: Like I said: don't forget the [vendor prefixes](http://www.ubelly.com/2012/02/vendor-prefixes-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/). In the fiddle, I'm using a JS library called [`-prefix-free`](https://raw.github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree/gh-pages/prefixfree.min.js) that adds the vendor prefixes automatically.

Comment: Are you telling me that i'll need to -webkit-transition for Chrome, then -moz-transition for FF, then -ms-transition for IE etc.?! Dude... (By the way, it works now, that i've followed you advice, but what about browsers not supported by my CSS? Can -webkit be regarded as (almost) general?)

Comment: @KonradViltersten - If you think adding all the vendor prefixes yourself is too much of a hassle, then use -prefix-free. Or run your code through [prefixr](http://prefixr.com/).

Comment: Oh, no. I like to clutter my source code with (almost) redundant commands, preferably in huge extents, so i can hide the core idea behind the solution, haha. Just kidding. In fact, i've seen something called LESS is it to be preferred to Prefixr? I haven't got this kind of problems before so i'm unsure which is the **right** approach. Please advise.