# Two transitions at once

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions

In [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622883/animating-specific-corners-on-hover-with-jquery/11622955#comment15392078_11622955) some great pointers were given. Now, i'd like to use not only

```
-webkit-transition: border-radius 0.5s;
```

but also

```
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
```

and then go

```
div.menuItem:hover {
  border-radius: 145px 85px 145px 85px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

When i only do one transition at a time, it works fine but i don't know how to combine those.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Separate them by a comma.

```
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s, border-radius 0.5s;
```

Demo: **[=)](http://jsfiddle.net/97dX5/)**

Comment: I swear at God, i just tried it and it didn't work. I must have forgot the comma or something (put a period, instead). Thanks.